# What kind of grin was Raj hinted to have?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-big-bang-theory

In S11E20 of The Big Bang Theory, Rajesh compliments Wolcott's tomatoes. He tells him that the tomatoes were fertilized with human manure. Howard and Leonard joke

> The look on your face.
>
> It's a sort of grin, wanna know what kind?

Not being a native English-speaker, I'm missing the joke here. I assumed it was an expression, maybe something like [this](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=shit%20grin), but I'm not sure. **What kind of grin did Raj have?**

Comment: I am okay with spoilers, but I can't tolerate spelling mistake in the name. ;-P

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Close, but (given the context) the reference is presumably to a [*shit-**eating**-grin*](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/shit-eating_grin):

> **1.** (*idiomatic, vulgar*) A broad smile indicating self-awareness that may suggest self-satisfaction, smugness, discomfort, or embarrassment.

Comment: The implication in the joke is that by eating tomatoes fertilized with manure (Which is a pretty traditional method) is that by extension, you have eaten the manure as well.

Comment: @JohnP : Even more : as a native English speaker, I hear "manure" with the connotation of animal faeces and "shit" with the connotation of human faeces.

Comment: @EricTowers - as a `Murican, we use **shit** for any feces - dog shit, horse shit, etc. Manure would be reserved for stuff meant as fertilizer. "Sitting through a shitty band. Getting **dog manure** on my hands" doesn't have the same ring.